# Como concatenar os resultados de uma RELAÇÃO em um SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Tendo as tabelas `PRODUTO` , `CATEGORIA` sendo que uma **CATEGORIA** pode ter vários **PRODUTOS**, gostaria que um `select` listasse em uma coluna **nvarchar**  todos os  **PRODUTO.NOME** de uma **CATEGORIA**.

Algo como:

```
       select concat( select p.nome from categoria c 
       inner join produto p on c.id = p.fk_categoria 
       where c.id = categoria.id) as ProdutosDaCategoria from categoria
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse código não vai funcionar mas é uma tentativa de explicar o que preciso.

Também teria que colocar uma "," ou outro caracter separador entre cada resultado da `subquery`.

Alguém sabe como fazer ?

Obs: qualquer solução que traga todas as **categorias** listadas e o "nome" dos **produtos** concatenados em um nvarchar atende o problema (desde que a query não fique inviavelmente cara ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fica aqui uma solução usando o FOR XML com o modo PATH

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.ID, 
       SUBSTRING((
          SELECT ', ' + P.NOME
          FROM dbo.Produtos P
          WHERE P.FK_CATEGORIA = C.ID
          FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) TODOS_OS_PRODUTOS
FROM dbo.Categorias C
ORDER BY C.ID
```

Fica aqui o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a3c3/2)

Comment: Deu certinho !!! Muito obrigado !!!!!!!

Comment: De nada, ainda bem que ajudou.

Comment: Muito legal ! Não sabia que no for xml path se vc colocasse + 'algumastring' ele deixava de exibir as tags pra exibir ela no lugar , isso vai ajudar muito !!

Answer (score 0):

sem a estrutura do banco de dados fica um pouco complicado para lhe ajudar, mas de qualquer forma tente realizar dessa maneira.

```
select processo.numero , Concat(descricao_parcela.nome,', ', outro_campo) as objetosDaAcao 
  from processo
  left join parcela 
    on >>>> veja as ligações necessarias <<<<
  left join descricao_parcela 
    on descricao_parcela.id = parcela.fk_descricao_parcela 
 where processo.id = parcela.fk_processo 
 order by processo.id
```

no concat vc define a forma e os campos que vc irá precisar se serão separados por ponto, virgula, aspas e por ai vai, só repasse a função com aspas simples e separe por virgula todos os campos e caracteres que for adicionar.

Veja a ligação correga para a tabela parcela no mais caso não funcione mande uma mensagem que lhe ajudo !!
Abraço...

Comment: desculpa , fiz uma alteração no post pra que ele tivesse somente 2 tabelas e ficasse mais simples . Vou tentar sua solução agora e já trago um feedback ! No caso não necessita da estrutura das a não ser saber as FKS , sendo  que um processo tem um id , parcela tem fk_processo e fk_descricao_parcela e descricao_parcela tem id. No exemplo que modifiquei levo em consideracao que um produto tem um fk_categoria e categoria um id . o exemplo deve servir pra concatenar qualquer campo

Comment: Seu exemplo não vai dar certo... porque eu não quero exibir um resultado de uma relacao e sim TODOS os resultados concatenados e ele so funcionaria pra quando uma categoria tivesse apenas um produto . De qualquer forma muito obrigado por tentar ajudar !

Comment: A função concat apenas ficou disponível no SQL Server 2012

Comment: sim mas para a versao 2005 ou 2008 em diante utilizando (campoX, ', ',campoY) as colunaX ele ja interpreta e realiza a concatenação, tinha me esquecido disso, estou acostumado com a 2014